# conflict between angular.json css styles setting and component css setting

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4

When both `angular.json's` CSS setting and component CSS setting are used,
component CSS setting is partially not working.

I want to apply component CSS setting in specific component.

Comment: Show us the code of your component.

Answer (score -1):

You can set

```
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
```

in you @component annotation

It means that CSS we write globally will inherit, however styles defined using the same class inside the Component will override existing styling.

Also Component's CSS has high priority than global css defined in `.angular-cli.json` file